# Type Challenge 11 Tuple to Object

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

I am fairly new to strong typing but have been working in TypeScript for a little while now. I am starting to work through the Type Challenges to get better at strong typing and having a strong intuition about the type system in TypeScript.

Currently, I am wondering about the difference between these two options for declaring a type:

```js
type TupleOptions = Array<number | string>;

type TupleOptions = (number | string)[];
```

My understanding is that they *should* be equivalent. However, I am working on [11 - Tuple to Object](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00011-easy-tuple-to-object/README.md) and seeing a difference when trying to use them.

```js
// this works
type TupleToObject<T extends readonly (number | string)[]> = {
  [key in T[number]]: key;
}

// this does NOT work
type TupleToObject<T extends readonly Array<number | string>> = {
  [key in T[number]]: key;
}
```

I'm still new so this very much confuses me.

...And, beyond that issue I am interested to learn why - for this challenge - using `any[]` (errors) and `(number | string)[]` (passes) produces different results for the final test in the challenge:

```js
// @ts-expect-error
type error = TupleToObject<[[1, 2], {}]>
```

Direct link to [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBCM0QtBAKgVwA4BsCmEAuB7CAeQCMArLAY10gXnodpIE8IBnASwDt98uIAFAAFOPPgEoIAYiwBDNqyn5yVXPADWWZmzC0p+iAEUUWNrg59dUAOIcAbln6ynAJxezmAGjzuubAGb4LgC2EBy4YVwEEM4QyhTUeMxoOM4AJngAFjiazMB2shgmEMEoZhAkONxZOGgu+HYcaVgZsm4eAHRWEABiQRBYAB6ywZhYAFzdAAYzuDpQlHzluOjYEAC8EADaAOS4phiyO947wfjNGBAAzMcQp+dYlwAat-cXEACaOwC6MWwQiz8NFouGSOBcphQGAim1QYyQ+FICVwAB5QSl8P48KssAA+CDAYADQYpagtCAAbzu+zYhx242pByOJzO7xuDLej2ur1ZXJeHN5zx5D0uXwFIs+OwAvrQZlNuviAGocLAAdzi-FsuAAEigSAzMrhcGg2ONCXNKJkOmQ2B0ggBzYCwMAgYC6UAQAD63p9vp9n3wKBcEAAwg8INqsBCvX7Y56IK73UT0Tg4dgiGhzEsNhAAILtZgorgoYKVYMAH3YuBc3HtuIA3GBCUkUsgcRms34cwJi6WoxBK2Ya1x7eItt9Gym2-DESpqCikMT9lw0v8IbI0nwMKweyWywOq8PR+P8ZsKbQtrlIsgtr2y99vgzco2ZU2QDG477kKYIiH5KYP0-b0EzdDhRiCCIpypABRABHFBCm8aCSVUCApQgfx6lCHYhBTeBLUKbAR1MYAUHMDA2B2XRAWWHEc12Gk6RZCUbmY94XjYrkvl+eQASWGgaMgnEADk937TYtmgbwACZvCubwABYeP+QSwEE7ExgAWQ4QZ6Kku5pNueS7gUn4-j4oFdCnSh-3+CTaGQ0lUTghCMAXHEESRVQ0TBTENOwXFvCpRjZA5EKdnrO5BW5cU2QiqKJX5BL2PizlRXpZKuJ2NDcUChyUPnFzCncmcvPnFM-JWMZRL7FxAspGAGWgSLpIZaTIquBkrkihSGQUnK8qgRzvKKty0ywTy51RCqsSq7BtMGeqqWgJrIp2QyOUMjqurW0yOVMgbPDAb4kwgXC2HgIYnMutwgjAKco3qYNYQ82dkRRLZJJk74gqlb5cXdd8gK-Hog1wbJgwAZX2E1AKAkC31ofFIcyNocGYQNgzYfAik7U0IENY1TXNNhLWtW0HSdaBgGcNhVSjJGIGVNV2BxsiLD8A0jRNM1gAtK0bTtFxHVgYBsdxjn5ggfFNKCHAQ1RjAiPtUwuaJ3n+fJoX7RdN0gA)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `readonly Array<...>`'s error message ("'readonly' type modifier is only permitted on array and tuple literal types") explains why it doesn't work. Use `ReadonlyArray<number | string>` instead. `any[]` works because it allows any type. However, you passed a tuple containing an object, which cannot be used as a key. Therefore, the result is an empty object type `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array<T>` and `T[]` are equivalent. However, there's one special piece of syntax sugar that only works on the latter. Specifically, `readonly T[]` translates to `ReadOnlyArray<T>`. So you should regard `readonly T[]` as a sort of special syntax entirely distinct from `T[]`; the only reason it's in the language at all is that people don't like writing out a long name like `Array<T>` for a common type like arrays.